# Calling existing make command in cmake file

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have a large project with multiple subdirectories. In the parent directory, I have a CMakeLists.txt file which calls functions defined in other `cmake` files in the same parent directory. I have a custom `Makefile` in one of the subdirectories that contains some target `"run"`. When I call `cmake` from the parent directory, I want the `"run"` target located in the subdirectory makefile to execute. How should I do this ?

---

I understand that some people have suggested to use `add_custom_target` and `add_custom_command`, but I am still confused as to how to apply these commands to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you know, which file(s) are produced by Makefile in the subdirectory, and want to depend on these files, use `add_custom_command`:

```cmake
add_custom_command(OUTPUT <output-file>
                   COMMAND make run
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/<subdir>
)
```

This assumes that your `CMakeLists.txt` have a target, which depends or uses given file.

Otherwise, if you do not care which files are produced by Makefile, use `add_custom_target`:

```cmake
add_custom_target(<target_name> COMMAND make run
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/<subdir>
)
```

---

In both cases *WORKING_DIRECTORY* specifies directory which should be *current* for command executed.

If you want the target (in the second case) to be executed by default, add *ALL* option before the *COMMAND*.